# How To convert com.lowagie.text.Image to InputStream?

Tags: java

I have tried the below code but i am getting can cout cast to RenderedImage exception.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write((RenderedImage) image,"jpg", outStream );
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(outStream .toByteArray());
```

I

Comment: Do you care about the format of the bytes in the InputStream?  What do you plan to do with the InputStream?

Comment: yes... actually i missed it in question. But i need RenderedImage as image object then... converted to input stream... I tried the solution one given below but that doesnt work for me for the same reason.

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
ByteArrayInputStreamoutStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(image.getOriginalData());
```